# Actionscript 3: check if string contains another string

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I check if a string contains another string in flash / Actionscript 3 ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine if a string contains a specific substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733935/how-to-determine-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-substring)

Comment: in fact, if you type in the title of this question into google, that is the first result.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
var a = "hello world";
if(a.indexOf("world") >= 0){
//It contains the String!
}
```